# Run simultaneous tasks after a BackgroundWorker has completed

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, backgroundworker

I'm using `BackGroundWorker` to stream a text file in the backgorund.

When this is completed I want to run two simultaneous `Tasks` which involve two methods with heavy calculations. These methods used the streamed data to do the calculations.

Somehow I've been stuck. The first part is executed and I'm able to stream the data. But the second part involving the calculations doesn't execute.

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker _streamworker = new BackgroundWorker();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _streamworker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    _streamworker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    _streamworker.DoWork += StreamData;
    _streamworker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    _streamworker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void StreamData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Stream a Text file here
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(HeavyMethod1);
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(HeavyMethod2);

    Task.WaitAll();

    // After the calculations have ended
    // Do something with the calculate results here
}

private void HeavyMethod1()
{
    // Some heavy calculations
}
private void HeavyMethod2()
{
    // Some heavy calculations that are not 
    // related to the ones in HeavyMethod1
}
```

**Update:**
One very very odd thing that I have noticed is that if I put `MessageBox.Show("");` before the calculations everything works fine!

```
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(HeavyMethod1);
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(HeavyMethod2);

    Task.WaitAll();
    MessageBox.Show("");

    // After the calculations have ended
    // Do something with the calculate results here
}
```

Comment: What do you meant by *doesn't execute*? Any exception? Did you tried to debug?

Comment: You don't pass anything to `Task.WaitAll();`, so wait nothing...

Comment: @L.B I thought if I don't pass it will consider them all by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't wait for anything. Just use `task1` and `task2`

```
Task.WaitAll(new Task[]{task1, task2});
```

**Update**

With MessageBox, you give a chance to tasks to complete their Works.

Comment: Thank you so much EZI, I missed my afternoon nap trying to solve this!